# Why am I getting the wrong division answer?

Tags: javascript, math, division

Super simple - I'm running a useEffect function in React. I need to do a simple calculation, but I keep getting the wrong answer.

Example, I get `10` as an answer instead of the expected `8,960...`

I thought it might be a string and not an Int at first, but it made no difference.

```js
const price = 5.58;
console.log(price); // returns 5.58
const money = 50.00;
console.log(money); // returns 50
const dev = parseInt(money) / parseInt(price);
console.log(dev) // returns 10 ???.
```

I expected it `const dev` to return `8,960573476702509` but it returned `10`

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat

Comment: `parseInt(5.58)` = 5...

Comment: Why do you expect 50 / 5 to return 8.90...?

Comment: use `parseFloat` instead of `parseInt`. E.g. `parseFloat(money) / parseFloat(price)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're doing division between two integers, as `parseInt(50.00)` will give `50` and `parseInt(5.58)` gives `5`, so your calculation will be doing `50/5` which is equal to `10`. To perform math with your floating-point numbers, there is no need to parse them as they're already floats:

```js
const price = 5.58; // already a float
console.log(price); // returns 5.58
const money = 50.00; // already a float
console.log(money); // returns 50
const dev = money / price;
console.log(dev) // 8.960573476702509
```

Comment: Yes, that's better. The problem is that in plain maths we often jump between number sets - if you write down `11 / 2` on a piece of paper and give it to somebody, they will not hesitate to give you an answer of `5.5` or `5 1/2`. But that's going from an integer to a real number or rational number. In JS all you have is floats so `5` is not actually an integer but in, say, Java or C `int a = 11; int b = 2; a / b` will result in an integer because `int / int -> int`

Comment: @VLAZ yeah, for some reason I had it in my head that integer division was division between two integers, but now that you've clarified it makes total sense. Cheers :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `parseFloat` as you are dealing with decimal number

```js
const price = 5.58;
console.log(price); 
const money = 50.00;
console.log(money); 
const dev = parseFloat(money) / parseFloat(price);
console.log(dev)
```

Comment: Those numbers are already *numbers*. Using `parseFloat` makes no sense.

Comment: Makes sense depending of what you want / expect to get. If you want to get `10` it makes no sense to use parseFloat, if you want to get 8.96... you need to use parseFloat

Comment: No, it still doesn't make sense. `parseFloat(5.58)` will not give you *more* of a float, since you are already giving it a float. At best, you get the same value back. However, since *parsing* is done on strings, what actually happens is that the value would be turned from numeric to a string and then transformed to a numeric again. This *might* lead subtle bugs with some values, if the string representation differs slightly.

Comment: Oh! I understand! Thanks a lot! @VLAZ

Answer (score 1):

```js
const price = 5.58;
console.log(price); // returns 5.58
const money = 50.00;
console.log(money); // returns 50
const dev = money / price;
console.log(dev) // returns 10 ???.
```

Comment: The two values are already numeric - there is no reason to run then through `parseFloat`.